# Oil and sulge in water colling system VW golf MK4 1.6

Tags: oil, vw, cooling-system, oil-in-coolant

[image]

Hie guys

I had oil and sulge in my water cooling system. took out all the coolant and replaced it with clean coolant. took a test drive had the same oil in my system again. what could be the problem?

Comment: Look at that linked question, and also look at your oil and see how it looks - does it have water in it or is it pure oil?  Search with those results.  We have several "oil in coolant" and vice versa.